# What are some reactions which can be used to study "Effect of Catalyst on the Rate of Reaction"?

Tags: catalysis

I wish to study the effect of catalyst on the rate of reaction as an investigatory project. 
What are some reactions and ideas that I could use to study this?

One example to this is the decomposition of $\ce{KClO_3}$ with $\ce{MnO_2}$ catalyst, The time for which $\ce{O_2}$ is evolved can be studied while varying the amount of catalyst.

**What are some similar nice reactions with which notable changes in the reaction with changing amount of catalyst can be observed ?**

**What can be other changes I could bring in the reaction to study different aspects of the reaction and this topic effectively?**

Suggestions please.

I know this question is open ended but please feel free to suggest anything that comes to your mind that can be done in high school laboratory.

Comment: KClO3 is dangerous, and this question too broad.

Comment: @Mith Well, the OP *does* use the word "some" here, i.e- he's asking for a few, notable/striking examples. He doesn't appear to be asking "*Give me a list of all such reactions*". So not too broad IMHO O:)

Comment: @paracetamol It's open ended, everyone could add another answer, claiming his "some reactions" are better. It's opinion-based if reaction is "amazing". At least what OP considers "similar" to mentioned one should be clarified, and it should be something other then "can kill you if you won't do it properly".

Comment: @Mith "*It's open ended*" <--- True, that. But not the same as "*too* broad". And yeah, the "amazing" bit should probably go. As for "similar reactions", the OP probably meant "other reactions that proceed rapidly in the presence of a catalyst" (or something like that). Wanna make the edit? :D

Comment: @above I have made some edits, so you might want to suggest something now that I have added some details.